# How to reduce the Querying time for larger size data in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

I am trying to querying the collection in MongoDB which matches more than 10000 data for the query. Even though I have used index, the querying time exceeds 25 seconds.

For example, I am having a table `People` with field `name, age`.
I need to fetch the People data whose age is 25, if query finds the matched objects is 10000, then it takes time to fetch the whole data.

I have created index like `db.people.createIndex({"age":1})`

Here, how can I reduce the querying time

Answer (score 0):

run db.collection.find().explain() and make sure that your index is in fact used. Make sure that you do not have COLLSCANs there https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/.

if your documents have some/many large attributes and you need only some attributes try to request only them (e.g. only _id or _id and name). Less data transferred gives higher speed.

if your db does not fit in memory, make it fit in memory. Once the database does not fit the performance will be much worse.

if you are not running on a sharded cluster, create one based on a reasonable sharding key. Age may not be a good one because than all age=25 documents will end up on one node. Even if you have one computer with multiple CPUs it still may work better for you (if you have enough memory for that). It may even work the other way around. If you have a sharded cluster on one computer and your replicas do not fit in the memory, it may be better to use just one node.

Comment: I checked with db.collection.find().explain(), and I am sure that my indexing is working

I used only the required fields i.e., upto 7 fields

and I am using shared cluster

Comment: good, what about the rest of the list? How large is your database? does it fit in memory and how large is your mongodb cluster?

Comment: 2.5 GB of total used space is 1.75GB

Comment: can you provide the find command or the pipeline query and output of the explain for that same command?